# Why blackberry apps cannot do network i/o AT ALL outside of North America without BIS?

Tags: networking, blackberry, java-me, connection

I was told by a consultant in a 3 hours discussion that basically blackberry 3rd party apps (Distributed through AppWorld or not) **cannot** perform any network I/O outside of North America without becoming an alliance member. Is this true?

Basically the story is that only North America can make use of APN connection, anywhere else in the world you have to rely on BIS for your network connection. And the network connection over BIS can only be made to a server that is provisioned by RIM. You will have to become and alliance member in order to have your server provisioned.

This sounds kinda silly to me, because if I am a third party developer I cannot do network io at all outside of NA. That's a huge limitation on the AppWorld developers!

---

I'm not talking about a network socket over Wifi connection, only concerned with network connectivity over the cell network.

Comment: Wow, that sucks. Glad I don't deal with BlackBerry!

Comment: There is like 3tier alliance membership plan. Tier 1 is free. But does that make you eligible for doing your connections over bis?

Comment: No, it does not, I just checked with RIM the free level does not let you do connections over bis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you may have been misinformed, or perhaps munging a couple of issues.

You can set up APN for many carriers:
http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Connect-to-Internet-with-Your-BlackBerry-without-Paying-For-Data-Plan
http://www.blackberryfaq.com/index.php/Carrier_specific_APN/TCP_settings

This is not "Blackberry Data Services", which do seem to have some restriction based on the carrier's provisioning.  Some applications - Verichat and Berry411 are mentioned in the above links - are clearly not restricted to the Blackberry Data Services, though, so I think that would be a bit overgeneralized to say -all- third party applications. (Perhaps the consultant meant third party applications that integrate with Exchange/BES have to go over a BIS link?  Or applications that require a secure interface?)

I also think it's not quite fair to say "outside of North America," as such services are clearly in use in the EU and India, at least, where various providers (O2, Vodafone) sell Blackberrys to actual customers.

I haven't used a Blackberry in several years, but even in my days there was a differentiation between Blackberry data and TCP data sent to the internet, with Opera being a ubiquitous example of a non-Blackberry connection.

Of the three answerers, we seem skeptical, and as far as I can tell none of us has been able to find anything to back up the consultant's claim, and indeed have found several counterpoints that seem to indicate the issue is at least incompletely understood.  Have you considered asking the consultant via e-mail to clarify?

Comment: You are right in that all carriers probably have APN settings. Unfortunately, no data plan in the world includes APN network traffic except north america. So yes the application will work but it'll cost them a lot outside of their already paid data plan.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. The Android platform uses APN exclusively for data. Some carriers web browser plans, intended for "non-smartphone" that have web capablility through WAP do not include direct TCP data. On those plans using direct TCP may be blocked, or very expensive, depending on the carrier. Also some Blackberry plans are limited to IM, social media, web browsing and email. Using a random port on those plans could be very expensive.

Offering a bounty isn't going to change the truth.

Comment: What? You've basically just repeated my point and supported it. Basically not all carriers offer TCP traffic as part of the normal data plan. The data plan they have might be limited to WAP traffic or blackberry BIS traffic. In which case the app will fail when trying to do real TCP traffic.

Comment: I can't speak for Richard, but I think we are all three in agreement that many (most? all?) carriers that offer data can use APN - it's just cost at that point, and certainly some carriers might block non-well-known ports.  Glancing over some pricing (Vodafone, O2) for Europe it appears that data isn't as punitive as in the US; at least one other discussion specifically mentioned Opera over APN on the BB so I think we're still apples and apples there.  To the requester, I'd say that 'expensive' is different than 'cannot', and a cost analysis can be made depending on use and carriers.

Comment: No I didn't. I said "Some carriers web browser plans..." that would be some specific plans, designed for specific, but not smart phone, devices, don't support APN data. For example, the Rogers pay as you go, $7/month data add on is only for WAP data. If you use APN data you (until very recently) would pay $0.05/kB. Now you can pay $2.99/20MB for a day. However, if you get a smart phone plan from rogers (for iPhone, Blackberry or Android) you can use APN data up to your plan limit. From talking to other devs/users there are providers outside NA that offer simalar complex stables of plans.

Comment: Richard, what you are saying is in direct support of what EVERYONE HERE IS SAYING. Perhaps you should spend some time reading what other people write before typing away with your keyboard. As you said, different carriers have different structure and more often than not, the user will not be free to use APN connection and hence the app will be crippled unless the user chooses to pay more.

Comment: So what you are saying (or asking) is that if a user buys a smart phone, blackberry in this case, but doesn't provision it with an APN data plan thus avoiding a regular tarrif; but then uses (or tries to) APN data anyway and is charged the very high ad-hoc tarrif (or blocked) this is some how wrong? A user wanting to use an app that uses APN or BIS-B data has to pay for it somehow. App developers wanting to implement BIS-B have to pay for that. You started by complaining that BB apps outside NA couldn't use APN, then complained that it is expensive. Expensive != cannot.

Answer (score 2):

A little Googling turned up a number of APN lists for carriers. [Here is one](http://modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/Carrier_APN_Settings) with one or two carriers that aren't in North America, it specifies iPhone, but generally APN settings by carrier are hardware agnostic. Of course I can't test them out since I am.

Answer (score 2):

This forum post has APN info for several carriors outside of the US and it appears that if that is correctly set in the device then 3rd party apps should work:

[Blackberry Forums](http://www.blackberryforums.com/blackberry-network/2185-blackberry-internet-msn-chat-web-telnet-tcpip-no-bes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry can definitely connect using APN outside north america. I've recently made an app (on the storm) and it it worked fine here in the Netherlands.

The real nightmare of APN on the blackberry is not that it doesn't work, it has to do with the fact that the app has to have the APN settings IN the app itself (instead of being able to use the settings as specified in the global phone settings. Using these settings things just won't work).

Can you imagine a user having to figure out his/her APN settings in every app they download?!?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some official documentation for [Accessing BlackBerry Data Services Using Wi-Fi Networks (PDF)](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/ataglance/networks/Accessing_BlackBerry_Data_Services_Via_Wi-Fi.pdf) from BlackBerry.

I would be surprised if you can't do wifi anywhere it is available, but maybe you are right.  [Here's a link](http://uk.blackberry.com/ataglance/networks/#tab_ddetail_subtab_wifi) the UK support pages, which aren't very clear about restrictions.

This probably doesn't help, but I bought a Bold 9700 without a contract here in North America and my BlackBerry application could connect to my home wifi network without any problems.

I will be in the UK in January so I can test it out then!

Answer (score 0):

Not True.
I have a APN Data plan for my Blackberry here in Mexico using Telcel as a carrier.
I also have the normal BIS connection. The reason I need the APN is because my company installs a BB app that needs TCP connection.

Oh, and by the way,

> You are right in that all carriers probably have APN settings. Unfortunately, no data plan in the world includes APN network traffic except north america. So yes the application will work but it'll cost them a lot outside of their already paid data plan. – erotsppa

My BIS+APN data plan is unlimited, so no extra charges besides the rent.