# HTTPS connection fails with IOException: "APN not specified" (Blackberry)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, midp

My Java ME Midlet works fine on Java phones and the BlackBerry simulator, but I can't receive a connection on a BlackBerry. I see a message that asks for permissions to connect, but when I select yes, it doesn't connect and instead throws an IO exception with the message APN not specified. Does anyone know why this might be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APN needs to be set up - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898075/why-blackberry-apps-cannot-do-network-i-o-at-all-outside-of-north-america-without)

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is in permissons on your device?

1. Open Options/Security/Application Permissions
2. Select your application name
3. Select Edit Permissions from the menu
4. Configure the Security Permissions to \"Allow\" for all categories.
5. Save the changes